# Cumulative month javascript - power bi

Tags: javascript, powerbi

I am using power slicer in power BI to use in filter selection.

I need them to be selected every month until the current month.

I'm using getMonth() (code in javascritp) but it only returns me the current month and I need them all up to the current month (example: it's September, so I need it to return me January, February, March, April, may, june, july, august and september)

Comment: please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask to improve your question

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.